# Error with Custom LWRP when upgrading from Chef 12.3.0 to 12.7.2

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me why i'm having a specific issue with a custom LWRP i've created a while back.

With Chef 12.3.0, my custom LWRP attributes work perfectly fine defined this way:

```rb
attribute 'name',               'kind_of' => String, 'name_attribute' => true
attribute 'older_than',         'kind_of' => Integer, 'default' => 60
attribute 'cron_month',         'kind_of' => String, 'default' => '*'
attribute 'cron_day',           'kind_of' => String, 'default' => '*'
attribute 'cron_minute',        'kind_of' => String, 'default' => '1'
attribute 'cron_hour',          'kind_of' => String, 'default' => '3'
attribute 'log_file',           'kind_of' => String, 'default' => '/var/log/curator.log'
....
```

With Chef 12.7.2, Attempting to specify "properties" the same way causes the following error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
----------------------------------
Property older_than must be one of: {"kind_of"=>Integer, "default"=>60}!  You passed 7.
```

The LWRP properties (previously attributes) don't work when defined like the previous example. It appears symbols must be used instead of strings.  If I covert the code to the following format, it works fine:

```rb
property 'name',               kind_of: String, name_attribute: true
property 'older_than',         kind_of: Integer, default: 60
property 'cron_month',         kind_of: String, default: '*'
property 'cron_day',           kind_of: String, default: '*'
property 'cron_minute',        kind_of: String, default: '1'
property 'cron_hour',          kind_of: String, default: '3'
property 'log_file',           kind_of: String, default: '/var/log/curator.log'
....
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is a problem nor can I find anything in the Chef changelog that would indicate this method of defining properties/attributes is no longer supported. From my understanding of Ruby, although I'm far from being an expert, strings can be used the place of symbols and vice versa.  Is there a simple reason for this or is this potentially a bug in Chef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on IRC (please don't cross-post), the fact that strings used to work was accidental and was not part of the API. Using symbols for keyword arguments is the standard in Ruby and we adhere to that. This was probably changed in 12.5 when we rewrote the internals of resource property handling to be a bit more self-contained, along with introducing the new `action`-in-resource syntax and a few other things.

Comment: Sorry I had posted this before going to the IRC chat. The goal was not to cross-post but to increase my chances of getting an answer to the question considering I didn't figure I'd get one so quickly. Thanks again.  On a side note, for anyone interested in viewing the PR for this, it's available here: https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/4681

Comment: "More quickly" for you means more work for the support volunteers. If it's been a while on one platform, it's cool to ask elsewhere but doing a cross-system blast for a basic question means you increase the likelihood of multiple volunteers spending time on the request.

Comment: @coderanger.  I'm curious about something.  While allowing strings was 'accidental', it was nonetheless the way things worked.  Thus, changing it was a breaking change, and many projects only allow those in major releases.  For my own future knowledge, was this simply an accident that a breaking change occurred in a minor release?  Or does the core team allow breaking changes in cases, like this one, where the now broken functionality was never approved behavior. (which is perfectly reasonable, just not what I am used to seeing.)

Comment: Stuff that wasn't supposed to work in the first place wouldn't be a breaking change. Same reason we can change non-public APIs without a major release. A major rev is for an incompatible change to a documented, supported, public API.

Comment: If we had noticed somehow, we probably would have fixed it sooner, but not being part of the API means it has no tests so the only way we notice is user reports.